# convert file name string into number matlab

Tags: string, matlab, loops, filenames

I have filenames of the following variety:

u_results_901.xls

u_results_902.xls

u_results_903.xls

u_results_904.xls

u_results_905.xls

and so on, 50+ more

There's also

v_results_901.xls etc

and

zeta_results_901.xls etc

I need to run each file through a script that manages the data within the spreadsheet. I don't want to feed them through one by one.

How can I convert these fnames to numbers?
I can shorten the fnames using `strtok`, and then maybe `str2num` the remaining '901' string... but I'm not sure how to remove what's in front and behind the numbers.

Maybe `strread`?

Comment: If the pattern is similar. Try using multiple "substrings" to remove the last 4 characters (extension) and do the same for the starting ones. This is not an answer just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
fileSplit = strsplit(fileName,'_');
fileNumber = str2num(fileSplit(end));
```

Comment: I don't have `strsplit` in my toolbox.

Comment: Get it from FEX : http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21710-string-toolkits/content/strings/strsplit.m

Comment: Or use substring if you can : http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/substring.html